# Replace content of a fragment and remove old content - Android aplication

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have two fragments, one with a list of objects and the other objects selected in the first list. When I add an item from the first tab would have to recharge the second tab with new data. Now I'm doing it like this:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Fragment fav = new TabFavorites();
ft.replace(R.id.fav_layout, fav);
ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
ft.commit();
```

The problem is that the previous instance of the tab is not removed and remains in memory. How I can do? Any idea?

The other fragment is even more clear, when I update the fragment, button upgrade is duplicated, this is the code I use:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.actualizar:{
        Log.d("MENU","ACTUALIZAR");
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Fragment cha = new TabChannels();
        ft.replace(R.id.list_layout, cha);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.commit();  
    }
```

To add the button to update the ActionBarSherlock:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater = getSherlockActivity().getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_channels, menu);
}
```

I have removed the line: **ft.addToBackStack(null);**

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a workaround, I solved the problem like this:

```
TabFavorites tabFavorites = (TabFavorites) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.pager);
tabFavorites.reloadFavChannels();
```